# Ajax only Working on first element of Bootstrap Modal in WordPress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using **Bootstrap modal** and Ajax as well to submit my Booking Form for different Product. The Ajax submit is working but only for for the first Product. When I try to submit the booking form for other Products, it redirects to **404 Error Page**. I am trying to debug this for hours but didn't work.

**Here's my code:**

**COMPLETE MODAL FORM**

```
<div class="package-holder">
    <div class="row">
        <?php global $post;  $catquery = new WP_Query(  array(
            'cat' => 3,
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => ASC
        )); ?>  
        <?php   while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $id = get_the_id(); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6 box-wrap">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <div class="package-details">
                        <h3><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h3>
                        <p><?php echo $post->post_excerpt; ?></p>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg-<?php echo $id; ?>">More Details</button>

                        <a class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".book-form-<?php echo $id; ?>">Book Package</a>

                        <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg-<?php echo $id; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                  <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h4>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                                   </div>
                                  <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal bform fade book-form-<?php echo $id; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                  <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h4>
                                  </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="form-wrap">
                                            <form id="packageForm" method="post" class="clearfix">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                                        <label for="name" class="">Name</label>
                                                        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                                        <label for="phone" class="">phone</label>
                                                        <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone Number" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                                        <label for="email" class="">email</label>
                                                        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email Address" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                                        <label for="pref-date" class="">pref-date</label>
                                                        <input id="pref-date" name="pref_date" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Prefered Date" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="package" value="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                                                        <label for="message" class="">message</label>
                                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Write your Message here" required></textarea>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12 btn-wrap">
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="packageForm" />
                                                        <img class="gif" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/oval.svg'; ?>" class="gif" width="30" alt="loading" style="display: none;">
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="response"></div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>          
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <figure class="image-wrap row">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) ); 
                        ?>
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <div class="col-sm-12 box-wrap">
        <?php global $post;  $full_cat = new WP_Query(  array(
            'cat' => 4,
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => ASC
        )); ?>  
            <div class="row">
            <?php   while($full_cat->have_posts()) : $full_cat->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="package-details">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg-<?php echo $id; ?>">More Details</button>

                        <a class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".book-form-<?php echo $id; ?>">Book Package</a>

                        <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg-<?php echo $id; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                  <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h4>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                                   </div>
                                  <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal fade book-form-<?php echo $id; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Himalayan Rejuvenation  Package</h4>
                              </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="form-wrap">
                                            <form id="FullpackageForm" method="post" class="clearfix">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                                        <label for="name" class="">Name</label>
                                                        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                                        <label for="phone" class="">phone</label>
                                                        <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone Number" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                                        <label for="email" class="">email</label>
                                                        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email Address" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                                        <label for="pref-date" class="">pref-date</label>
                                                        <input id="pref-date" name="pref_date" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Prefered Date" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="package" value="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                                                        <label for="message" class="">message</label>
                                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Write your Message here" required></textarea>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12 btn-wrap">
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="FullpackageForm" />
                                                        <img class="gif" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/oval.svg'; ?>" class="gif" width="30" alt="loading" style="display: none;">
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="fullresponse"></div>
                                            </form>
                                    </div>          
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <figure class="image-wrap row">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) ); 
                        ?>
                    </figure>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: BOOKING FORM]
**From above code, the ajax form is**

```
<form id="packageForm" method="post" class="clearfix">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label for="name" class="">Name</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label for="phone" class="">phone</label>
            <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone Number" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label for="email" class="">email</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email Address" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label for="pref-date" class="">pref-date</label>
            <input id="pref-date" name="pref_date" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Prefered Date" required>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="package" value="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>">
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
            <label for="message" class="">message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Write your Message here" required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 btn-wrap">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="packageForm" />
            <img class="gif" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/oval.svg'; ?>" class="gif" width="30" alt="loading" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div id="response"></div>
</form>
```

**Handling Ajax Request via `functions.php`**

```
// Ajax for Package Form
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

function packageForm(){

global $wpdb;
$package_name =$_POST['package'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$date = $_POST['pref_date'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$quote = 'Package Name:'.$package_name."\n\r".'Full Name: '.$name."\n\r".'Phone: '.$phone."\n\r".'Email: '.$email."\n\r".'Available Date: '.$date."\n\r".'Message: '.$message;
$to = 'prabin.b9@gmail.com'; // put your email here
$headers = 'From:Himalayan spa <info@himalayanbodycare.com>' . "\r\n"; // put user's email here or duplicate your email
$subject = 'Request For Spa';

if(wp_mail($to, $subject, $quote, $headers)===FALSE){
echo "Error";
}
else {
echo "<h3> Message Successfully Sent</h3>";
}
die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_packageForm', 'packageForm');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_packageForm', 'packageForm');
```

**Finally my `jQuery` in `custom.js`**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
jQuery('#packageForm').submit(packageSubmit);     
        function packageSubmit(){
           var ceccForm = jQuery(this).serialize();
            jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: ceccForm,
            success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            jQuery("#response").html(data);
            jQuery("#packageForm")[0].reset();
            }
        });
      return false;
      }
 }); 
    jQuery(document).ajaxStart(function(){
      jQuery('.gif').show();
            }).ajaxStop(function(){
      jQuery('.gif').hide();
    });
```

> As Mentioned earlier, The Ajax is working only for the first element
>   of the product as shown in the screenshot. Please Help !!

Comment: Is your form generate in loop ?

Comment: First make sure packageForm id is only one in whole page ?

Comment: Yes, that's the unique form *ID*.

Comment: I can see many in your site

Comment: they're not ID.

Comment: check @madalin's answer. It surely works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change all your ids to classes, select the response element based on the submit form

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
jQuery('.packageForm').submit(packageSubmit);     
        function packageSubmit(){
           var el = jQuery(this);
           var ceccForm = el.serialize();
            jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: ceccForm,
            success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            el.find(".response").html(data);
            el.reset();
            }
        });
      return false;
      }
 }); 
    jQuery(document).ajaxStart(function(){
      jQuery('.gif').show();
            }).ajaxStop(function(){
      jQuery('.gif').hide();
    });
```

Comment: You mean I should first change my form id to class and use your above code ?
`<form id="packageForm" method="post" class="clearfix packageForm">`

Comment: Thanx, it worked. But why ID didn't work ? Can you explain me a little please ?

Comment: Ids are UNIQUE when you call `jQuery('#packageForm')` you will always get the first element

Comment: Oh I had a concept of Ids and Classes but never knew IDs will only get first element only. Thanks a lot mate. You saved my day !!

Comment: javascript will only get the first element with that id

Comment: Hello, I'm using the different ajax form but with with class but it's redirecting to error page. can you help me on this ?
The site:
http://www.himalayanbodycare.com/

Error form:
Full Day Package booking form (other booking form works)

Comment: if you are redirecting then your ajax doesn't trigger

Comment: from what i can see you have different classes for it add a coma to the selector and add this new selectors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127595/discussion-between-prabin-parajuli-and-madalin-ivascu).